# Java esperar o fim da execução de um .bat

Tags: java

Estou com o seguinte cenário:

- Tenho uma aplicação Java com Swing;
- Onde por meio de um jTextField, eu pego uma informação;
- Com essa informação, eu crio um .bat
- Este .bat efetua a chamada de um arquivo .exe com os parâmetros obtidos pela jTextField.

Meu problema é que preciso que minha aplicação Java espere a finalização do arquivo .bat, pois para continuar o processo na aplicação Java sem erros, preciso das informações que esse .bat vai retornar.

Existe alguma função que verifica se o arquivo continua em aberto? Pois se tiver, eu posso fazer um loop até o momento que a tela for fechada.

Comment: Poderia complementar a pergunta com o código que está utilizando para fazer a execução do arquivo batch.

Comment: Por favor, forneça um  **[mcve]** para que seja possivel visualizar e testar o problema.

Comment: É um código simples que gera um arquivo .bat e no fim executa.

Comment: @Articuno, falei que era simples, olha a resposta do #escapistabr...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passei por algo semelhante e resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
Process procBat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec([comando]);
int retorno = procBat.waitFor(); // Se o retorno for 0 então o processo executou com sucesso
```

Comment: Acho que `process.waitFor()` deveria ser `procBat.waitFor()`, certo?

Comment: Exatamente, obrigado pela correção!